# New intellij/maven web application, advice on separating modules for service, dao, common libraries etc

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

So I created a new maven pom based webapp using intelliJ 11.

Now I want to separate out my various layers of the application, so I currently I have:

```
/myproj
/myproj-common (maven module)
/myproj-services (maven module)
/src/main/webapp  (spring mvc application)
```

So I am using the following:

```
spring mvc
hibernate
```

So I will create Dao for each entity, and then a service layer that will use the Dao's and wrap other business logic etc.

How should I setup my maven modules properly without making it too complicated?

Should I create a separate interface module that my other modules will use?

Looking for some practical advice.

I'm using maven to build this also.

I tried this before and moving things into separate modules can't be a little tricky, so looking for some guidance on how to do this.

**Update**

Should I have a separate module for my entities also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is use only one maven module and do separation on package level.

If you need more I can recomend this setup:

myproj-services - entity classes, service interfaces
myproj-services-impl - implementation dao and services
myproj-ui - your spring mvc classes

Ui depends only on services and services-impl depends only on services.

Comment: so hibernate will be inside the myproj-services-impl module?  I thought it would be a good idea to separate that no?

Comment: If you want to use Hibernate Annotations for your entity classes you have add this dependence to myproj-service.

Comment: Hibernate Core can be inside myproj-services-impl.

Answer (score 0):

To reply to your update: IMO yes.
To follow the DDD you should have a model module that contains your entities and DAO's and a service module for for your services.

One step further is splitting up the service module into a service-api module (service interfaces) and and service-lib module (implementations). This also entails then that you don't pass entities from your service module to your web modules by TO's (or views if you prefer).

Another related tip: if you're afraid your service classes will get too big (hence difficult to read/maintain/test) consider splitting them up into Business Objects. So, instead of having a UserService containing all the code you have a UserServiceFacade which delegates to MakeUserBO, FindUserBO, ... . These BO's are responsible for one (or more if related) tasks and can easily be reused by other services or other BO's. BO's are short, to the point and therefore easily to read/maintain. It is also easier to mock specific BO's while you're testing other.